# Floated Divs instead of a table to achieve layout

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am currently using a table with 2 rows, the top row has 3 columns, the bottom row has 2 columns.

can somebody please tell me how I would go about doing this same layout with floated divs? As I actually have no idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Float the `divs` but clear the 4th one? Or add margin to the right of the 3rd one?

Comment: Have you tried using css flexbox layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this example I've made for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/ADQ8g/

html:

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="row row1">
        <div class="column">
            content goes here
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            content goes here
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row2">
        <div class="column">
            content goes here
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row:after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}

.row1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.row2 {
    background-color: green;
}
.row1 .column {
    width: 33.3333%;
}

.row2 .column {
    width: 50%;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Explanation:
Each floating element needs to have a width set (since you're floating block elements which by default takes up 100% of it's container's width) in a way that allows several elements next to each other (50% for two elements, 33% for 3 elements, 25% for 4 elements and so on... you could also give specific sizes with pixels).

After you have done floating a "row" or elements, you need to clear the float with `clear:both`. I've used the `:after` pseudo element to save myself from creating an extra element with just the clear rule.

If you have more questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Although it looks like the expected result, the first row is smaller in width than the second. In case you add borders to the divs or content that fills the "table cells", you may notice a discrepancy between the right limits of the two rows

Comment: @chiapa, could you show me an example on my fiddle? I don't quite understand the problem...

Comment: Oh, I see what you did there. Yes, you are right. I'll correct the answer with `width: 33.3333%` for the 3 columns. That would give a more accurate result, making both rows with the same size (or significantly similar).

Comment: Sorry for being picky, it was just for the sake of accuracy!

Comment: Your comment is great and it's good to learn from. Picky is what makes a good code :)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="leftdiv">Column1</div>
<div class="centerdiv">Column2</div>
<div class="rightdiv">Column3</div>
<div class="leftdiv">Column4</div>
<div class="leftdiv">Column5</div>
```

**css**

```
.leftdiv { 
    background-color: red; 
    float: left;
}
.centerdiv { 
    background-color: orange; 
    float: none;
}
.rightdiv { 
    background-color: green; 
    float: right;
}
```

**Fiddle:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/L85rp/462/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="width-3">Content</div>
    <div class="width-3">Content</div>
    <div class="width-3">Content</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="width-2">Content</div>
    <div class="width-2">Content</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS is

```
.width-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
}
.width-2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

If you need padding to content, add a new division inside `width-2` or `width-3` instead of adding padding or margin to `width-2` or `width-3`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <div class="float-left bd-black w33">
      A11
   </div>
   <div class="float-left bd-black w33">
      A12
   </div>
   <div class="float-left bd-black w33">
      A13
   </div>
</div>
<div class="clear-both">
   <div class="float-left bd-black w495">
      A21
   </div>
   <div class="float-left bd-black w495">
      A22
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bd-black
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.float-left
{
    float: left;
}

.clear-both
{
    clear: both;
}

.w33
{
    width: 33%;
}

.w495
{
    width: 49.5%;
}
```

See if it suits you.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L85rp/465/)